# Абсолютное позиционирование с hover, но прозрачное

Tags: html, css, position

Возможно, моё решение является велосипедом. У меня стоит задача сделать выпадающее меню. Меню генерируется, по всей видимости, с php (которого я не знаю)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно по наведению на определенную ссылку реализовать выпадающее меню.
Посколько я не могу добавлять блоки внутри top-menu, я решил добавить ещё один блок, который был бы невидимым и при наведении активировал выпадающий список. Это я сделал. Проблема в том, что он перекрывает ссылку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно, чтобы ссылка работала вместе с выпадающим списком. Возможно ли это как-то реализовать с моей конструкцией?

```css
        .dropdown-content {
            
          display: none;
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
              left: 0px;
                top: 58px;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
          width: 140px;
          height: 25px;
          background-color: #b58f5b;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          z-index: 1;
        }
        .dropdown-wrapper {
        
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        
        
        top: 0px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 78px;
        }
        .dropdown-wrapper:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
         
        
        
        .dropdown-content a {
position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
<div><a href="#">о компании</a></div>
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос рабочий пример через "Фрагмент Кода" (ctrl + m). добавьте туда ваши стили, и сгенерированный html (без {include file="global:simplemenu.tpl" data=$menu2 class="top-menu"}). т.к. я сделал небольшой пример в песочнице и там все работает

Comment: Добавил рабочий пример кода @ТёмаKornishon

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon, мне нужно, чтобы ссылка тоже была активна, при этом выпадающий список работал

Comment: в данном примере не могу найти решения, скорее всего придется делать меню как надо. попробуйте допустим через вот такую конструкцию обойти меню и сгенерировать через свой шаблон {foreach key=k item=i from=$menu2}<a href="{$i}">{$k}</a>{/foreach}. k - ключ элемента массива, i - значение. Все зависит от модели $menu2. Внутри можно уже добавлять подменю, и в итоге и ховер и клик на одном элементе будут

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon, понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon, Вы мне дали идею) Я просто в этой "заглушке" сделаю ссылку